# Abort trap when freeing a pointer

Tags: c, memory

I created a function which would return an aligned memory pointer.
When I try to free it , I get an abort. I did allocate more memory to make sure I account for extra padding i did to make the pointer 64B aligned.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#define BYTE_ALIGNMENT 64
#define BYTE_ALIGNMENT_MASK BYTE_ALIGNMENT-1

void *memory_aligned(size_t size){

    void *ptr;
    ptr= malloc(size+BYTE_ALIGNMENT); //malloc more memory.

    if( ((uintptr_t)ptr & BYTE_ALIGNMENT_MASK) == 0){
          printf("already aligned %p\n",ptr);
          return ptr;

    }
    if( ((uintptr_t)ptr % BYTE_ALIGNMENT) == 0){
          printf("64 byte aligned %p\n",ptr);
          return ptr;

    } else{
        // check how many bytes are needed to make it 64 byte aligned.
        // ptr->8 64-8 = 56 bytes
        printf("Not 64 byte aligned %p \n",ptr);
        int padding = BYTE_ALIGNMENT - ((uintptr_t)ptr%BYTE_ALIGNMENT);
        ptr = ptr+padding;
        printf("should be now byte aligned %p \n",ptr);
    }

    return ptr;

}


int main(){

   void *ptr;
   ptr = memory_aligned(66);
    if( ((uintptr_t)ptr % BYTE_ALIGNMENT) == 0){ // make sure the pointer is byte aligned
          printf("64 byte aligned %p\n",ptr);


    }
   free(ptr);
   return 0;

}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
./a.out


 Not 64 byte aligned 0x7fddd7c02ae0 
should be now byte aligned 0x7fddd7c02b00 
64 byte aligned 0x7fddd7c02b00
a.out(25197,0x10ae035c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fddd7c02b00: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(25197,0x10ae035c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: The pointer passed to `free` must be the pointer returned from `malloc`.

Comment: You can only pass *the exact value you `malloc()`ed* to `free()`. If you want to mess around with alignment, you need to either keep around the original pointer and `free()` it, or be sane and just use `aligned_alloc()`.

Comment: That can't possibly work. You are returning a pointer inside allocated block, but this was not a pointer which was returned by malloc. You can't free it.

Comment: `mmap()` is your friend.

Comment: the posted code fails to compile!  there are several `error` messages from the compiler. How are we to help you with a run time problem when the code you post does not compile?

Comment: the type `uintptr_t` is defined in the header file: `stdint.h` which the posted code fails to include

Comment: why are you including the header files: stdio.h and stdlib.h as if they were 'home grown' header files.  The correct syntax is: `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: @user3629249 code I posted compiles perfectly fine on a mac. Though on linux it does get compile errors as you pointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comment, you can only free the exact pointer returned by malloc. If you want an aligned memory outside of the standard C datatype scope, you should probably use a function that was made for this purpose, such as [aligned_alloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/aligned_alloc).

The following code should work as intended.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <stdint.h>

#define BYTE_ALIGNMENT 64

int main(){

   void *ptr;
   int  size;

   size = 66;
   if (size % BYTE_ALIGNMENT)
       size += BYTE_ALIGNMENT - size % BYTE_ALIGNMENT;
   ptr = aligned_alloc(size, BYTE_ALIGNMENT);
   printf("%d\n", size);
   if( ((uintptr_t)ptr % BYTE_ALIGNMENT) == 0){ // make sure the pointer is byte aligned
          printf("64 byte aligned %p\n",ptr);
    }
    if (ptr)
        free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```